# How to feed a 4D tensor into LSTM model?

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to use an LSTM model to predict the future sales.

The data is like the table below.

| date | store | family | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2013 | 1 | AUTOMOTIVE | 0 |
| 01/01/2013 | 1 | BABY CARE | 0 |
| 01/01/2013 | 1 | BEAUTY | 1 |
| .. | . | .. | . |
| 01/01/2013 | 2 | AUTOMOTIVE | 0 |
| 01/01/2013 | 2 | BABY CARE | 0 |
| .. | . | .. | . |
| 01/01/2013 | 50 | AUTOMOTIVE | 0 |
| .. | . | .. | . |
| 01/02/2013 | 1 | AUTOMOTIVE | 0 |
| 01/02/2013 | 1 | BABY CARE | 50 |
| .. | . | .. | . |
| 01/02/2013 | 2 | AUTOMOTIVE | 500 |
| 01/02/2013 | 2 | BABY CARE | 0 |
| .. | . | .. | . |
| 01/02/2013 | 50 | AUTOMOTIVE | 0 |
| .. | . | .. | . |
| .. | . | .. | . |
| 12/31/2015 | 1 | AUTOMOTIVE | 0 |
| 12/31/2015 | 1 | BABY CARE | 50 |
| .. | . | .. | . |
| 12/31/2015 | 2 | AUTOMOTIVE | 500 |
| 12/31/2015 | 2 | BABY CARE | 0 |
| .. | . | .. | . |
| 12/31/2015 | 50 | AUTOMOTIVE | 0 |
| .. | . | .. | . |

> For each day, it has 50 stores.
> For each store, it has different type of family (product). (They are all in perfect order, thank God).
> Last, for each type of family, it has its sales.

Here is the problem.

The dimension of input of LSTM model is (Batch_Size, Sequence_Length, Input_Dimension). It is a 3D tensor.

However, in my case, my Input_Dimension is 2D, which is (**rows** x **columns**)
**rows**: number of rows in one day, which is 1782
**columns**: number of features, which is 2 (store and family)

Is there a good way to make my data into a shape which can be fed into a LSTM model?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The concept is straightforward. It works differently during learning and prediction however, so I'll explain the two cases separately.

- For training, you simply chop the part of your sequence that you chose as training data into smaller subsequences of time points. (You need to do this because the network is "unrolled" for the duration of those subsequences and it cannot be too big; if there is no obvious choice, 32 or 64 timesteps should be a good starting point.) To maximize the use of your data, you also want your subsequences to have some overlap. Both TF and PyTorch should have some helper functions that help you get this (such as `tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array`). You may find this article useful: https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2020/11/13/preparing-time-series-data-for-rnn-in-tensorflow/
- For prediction, you can just feed your sequence by reshaping such that it is a 3D tensor with the first dimension of size 1. Either `reshape` or `newaxis` in NumPy can get you this. Of course you don't need to feed your entire sequence, only a sufficient number of timesteps back as context to get the RNN's state to converge to something appropriate.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I understand the timesteps part.<br> Howerver, what I want to know is the **"input_dimension"** part. The input in both tensorflow and pytorch is (batch_size, timesteps, **input_dimension**). But input_dimension in my data is 2D, which lead to the input will be 4D. This doesn't fit in LSTM model.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to input the data of all the stores and all the family products in one day as one data point/timestep? Forget about dimensions, that is just bad modeling. Break down your model per store per day, with maybe a global network that accounts for seasonality or whatever other correlations between stores.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do it that way, lol.
I think I can give it a try and to see the result.
Then, maybe I will use PCA on my data to reduce the dimension of it.

Comment: What do you mean "accounts for seasonality".
Do you mean create several LSTM models and use them correspond to the season?

Comment: See my comment to your proposed solution. @88-gps

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with is to make the whole data in each day to be a long long long sequence.
So the dimension will be 1D, and can be fed into the LSTM model.

But I don't think this is the optimal solution.

Does anyone come up with better answer?
Appreciate.

Comment: Based on your comment to my response, that is the only way I know of to do it. You also don't have an advantage to reshape it another way. On the other hand, the network has to do a lot of extra work to understand that (1) the trends between stores are correlated, and thus (2) the prediction for one store can borrow from the learning of how to predict another store.